# How to access this element in JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a button and use jquery to change it id and class.

```
$("#button_a").on('click', function(){  

    $(this).removeAttr('id');
    $(this).removeClass('left btn btn-warning');        

    $(this).attr('id', 'button_b');
    $(this).addClass('left btn btn-success');

    $(this).text('SAVE');   

});

$("#button_b").on('click', function(){  

    alert('test');

});
```

When I tried access the `$('#button_b')` outside the `$('#button_a')` click event, it's not working.

How to activate it outside `$('#button_a')` click event?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you try to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#button_b` does not exist when the page loads - such an element only exists after `#button_a` is clicked. So, your `$("#button_b").on`, which *on page load* tries to assign a handler to `#button_b` fails, because it doesn't exist yet.

You might use event delegation instead. Also make sure to remove the existing listener on (the renamed) `button_a`, and to call `stopPropagation` so that the bubbling event (after the ID has changed) doesn't trigger the delegated event:

```js
$("#button_a").on('click', function(e){
  $("#button_a").off('click');
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).attr('id', 'button_b');
    $(this).text('SAVE');   
});
$(document).on('click', '#button_b', function(){  
  console.log('test');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button_a">click me</div>
```

The other option is to assign the new handler directly inside the `$("#button_a")` handler:

```js
$("#button_a").on('click', function(e){
  $("#button_a").off('click');
  $(this).on('click', function(){  
    console.log('test');
  });
  $(this).text('SAVE');   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button_a">click me</div>
```